# Docker-Compose running multiple instances of one image in different ports

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a python flask application and I want to have multiple instances of it at the same server that each container have own output port (or DNS) and dependencies. I used docker-compose and it works well. 
I saw `scale` arg but I think it is good for something like load balancing not having a different version of an application. Another solution that came up to my mind is having multiple services for one app and run each instance by its name in the terminal.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `docker-compose scale` command is deprecated and the docs suggest you use `docker-compose up --scale SERVICE=NUM`. But you must be careful when specifying ports for scaling. If you try to put your containers on port `80` five times, four of the five will fail - the port would be already occupied. But there is a solution.

I just tested this approach and it worked. Here's the `docker-compose.yml` I tested:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  test_app:
    image: <my_custom_image>
    ports:
      - 10000-10003:80
```

Then I ran it with `docker-compose up --scale test_app=4` and it deployed 4 instances of `test_app` on four different (but specified beforehand) ports: `10000`, `10001`, `10002` and `10003`.

I hope I answered your question.

Comment: Thanks! It's really helpful. But what happens for dependencies? I have a database for that application and I used `depends_on` to specify that as a dependency. I want to have all containers be isolated with each other.

Comment: Not gonna happen. All containers will be on the same network and therefore will be aware of one another. Generally, by default, everything you put in `services` in `docker-compose.yml` is gonna be on the same network, scale or not. You may connect one container from another by it's name you see when listing containers with `docker ps`.

Comment: Can you scale a single service in a docker-composr.yaml.  say I want to scale my actual service,.but all reading from a single db?

Comment: @mike01010 my answer will apply, beware of race condition though.

Answer (score 3):

One option is just duplicating the service in your docker compose file. Not the most elegant option, but then you could specific the port they the containers are listening on.
Example:

```
services:
  app1:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"  # Map host port 8000 to container port 8000

  app2:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8001:8000"  # Map host port 8001 to container port 8000
```